# how can i compare two dates based on month field in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I compare two dates based on month field in sql?

Could someone show an example of displaying employee names who have joined in those months when their managers joined?

I've tried these:

```
SELECT e_name
FROM emp5 e,
    department1 d,
    manager m
WHERE e.e_id = d.empno
    AND m.deptno = d.deptno
    AND month(e.hiredate) = month(m.hiredate);

SELECT e_name
FROM emp5 e,
    department1 d,
    manager m
WHERE e.e_id = d.empno
    AND m.dep tno = d.deptno
    AND month(e.hiredate) = month(m.hiredate)

SELECT e_name
FROM emp5 e,
    department1 d,
    manager m
WHERE e.e_id = d.empno
    AND m.deptno = d.deptno
    AND dd - mon - yy(e.hiredate, '%m-%y') = dd - mon - yy(m.hiredate, '%m-%y');



SELECT e_name
FROM emp5 e,
    department1 d,
    manager m
WHERE e.eid = d.empno
    AND m.deptno = d.deptno
    AND extract(month FROM e.hiredate) = extract(month FROM m.hiredate);
```

this is my emp5 table –

```
E_ID     E_NAME                   SALARY     HIREDATE 
----- ------------------------- ---------- --------- 
e01   Komal Pandya              13000       02-FEB-15 
e02   Ganesh Patel              20000       01-FEB-15
```

Comment: How is your date stored? What have you tried and what output is it resulting in? What output do you actually want?  Sample data and a query will go a long way toward getting you a meaningful answer.

Comment: SQL> select e_name from emp5 e,department1 d,manager m where e.e_id=d.empno and
m.deptno=d.deptno and month(e.hiredate)=month(m.hiredate);
select e_name from emp5 e,department1 d,manager m where e.e_id=d.empno and m.dep
tno=d.deptno and month(e.hiredate)=month(m.hiredate)
2.SQL> select e_name from emp5 e,department1 d,manager m where e.e_id=d.empno and
m.deptno=d.deptno and dd-mon-yy(e.hiredate,'%m-%y')=dd-mon-yy(m.hiredate,'%m-%y'
); 
 i tried these....

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are some informations on how to ask a good question

Comment: SQL> select e_name from emp5 e,department1 d,manager m where e.eid=d.empno and m
.deptno=d.deptno and extract(month from e.hiredate)=extract(month from m.hiredat
e); i tried this also.and E_ID  E_NAME                        SALARY HIREDATE
----- ------------------------- ---------- ---------
e01   Komal Pandya                   13000 02-FEB-15
e02   Ganesh Patel                   20000 01-FEB-15 this is my emp5  table

Comment: Please don't add code in the comments. Edit you question, as I just did, and put your code in proper code format (you can use the code button at the top of the edit window to properly format it).

Comment: sorry.But i could not find code button.I can't understand where to write code.Actually I have newly joined.Can't understand the environment.Please help me.

Comment: @MouliChanda That's better, but help us understand what's not working, the first query looks fine, `MONTH()` is a valid oracle function (might need year also, but the query should run in current state).

Comment: Your last query should work in Oracle. Assuming that you have a manager that started in the same month as an employee of the same department. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Also, as you build on this, understand that the same month occurs year after year, so a manager starting in Feb 2015, and an employee starting in Feb 2016 will appear as a match in this query. As far as code editting goes, if you add 4 spaces in front the line it will turn it into code. Optionally you can enclose code in backticks and it will `format it as code like this`.

Comment: What datatype is `HIREDATE`?  That doesn't look like a standard date format, but I don't know oracle very well.  If it's stored as a string, it shouldn't be, and you'll have to `TO_DATE()` it before you can run date functions on it, you could also `SUBSTR()` to parse the month portion if you can't change the underlying structure.

Comment: No no..HIREDATE is of DATE datatype.

Comment: @JNevill I am using oracle 10g express edition.And it's showing month is invalid identifier.

Comment: @MouliChanda As per Aleksej, `MONTH()` is not in that version, so you'll need to use `EXTRACT()` or `TO_CHAR()`.

Comment: I used extract too.But it was showing no rows selected.Though i have sufficient data.Would you please modify my query properly?

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but do you have proper data set up - which is to say that there is a department and manager record for your two indicated emp5 records?  If you run the query without matching on month - do you get results?

Comment: I did n't give total table here.Here it is:    E_ID  E_NAME                        SALARY HIREDATE
----- ------------------------- ---------- ---------
e01   Komal Pandya                   13000 02-FEB-15
e02   Ganesh Patel                   20000 01-FEB-15
e03   Puja Desai                     34000 01-MAR-15
e04   Kiran Shah                     25000 03-MAR-15
e05   Santa Singh                    15000 03-JAN-15
e06   Ankur Kahar                    24000 03-JUN-15
e07   Jane Donald                    14000 08-JUN-15
e08   Lidia Brown                    20000 08-JUL-15

Comment: There are 2 more records also.I did not show because I don't have sufficient space

Comment: Here is my manager table.              MGRNO     DEPTNO    MANAGER_NAME
                                   SALARY HIREDATE
--------- --------- --------------------------------
------------------------------ ---------- ---------
m1        d1        a
                                   100000 15-JAN-15
m2        d2        b
                                   200000 30-MAY-15
m3        d3        c
                                    30000 01-JAN-15
m4        d4        d
                                   400000 02-JAN-15
m5        d5        e
                                   500000 31-JAN-15

Comment: Can you please post all the records of your tables in the question, possibly well formatted? It's really hard to understand the situation in such a fragmented way

Comment: Yes I understand.Please tell me how to post tables in tabular format.I am really unable to do it.And I don't have sufficient space to post all records.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your dates are stored as `DATE` columns, these are two simple ways to extract month and year from a date:

```
SQL> select extract(month from sysdate), extract(year from sysdate) from dual;

EXTRACT(MONTHFROMSYSDATE) EXTRACT(YEARFROMSYSDATE)
------------------------- ------------------------
                        3                     2016

SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'mm/yyyy') from dual;

TO_CHAR
-------
03/2016
```

Comment: There's also the `MONTH()` function, which they're already using.

Comment: My ignorance, I've never used it; maybe it only exists on 12c? I've just tried on 11.2.0.2, but it seems not to exist

Comment: Oh that could be, I'm less familiar with oracle.

Comment: You can also extract the month from a date with  to_char(hiredate,'MONTH')

Comment: @Michael Broughton Still it's showing no rows selected.I did this        SQL> select e_name from emp5 e,department1 d,manager m where e.e_id=d.empno and
m.deptno=d.deptno and to_char(e.hiredate,'month')=to_char(m.hiredate,'month');

Comment: Do you get data if you drop the date comparison?  select e_name from emp5 e,department1 d,manager m where e.e_id=d.empno and m.deptno=d.deptno

Comment: Can you please post the result of `select e_name, e.hiredate, m.hiredate  from emp5 e,department1 d,manager m where e.e_id=d.empno and m.deptno=d.deptno`

Comment: Here is the output:    SQL> select e_name,e.hiredate,m.hiredate from emp5 e,department1 d,manager m whe
re e.e_id=d.empno and m.deptno=d.deptno;

E_NAME                    HIREDATE  HIREDATE
------------------------- --------- ---------
Komal Pandya              02-FEB-15 15-JAN-15
Ganesh Patel              01-FEB-15 15-JAN-15
Puja Desai                01-MAR-15 15-JAN-15
Kiran Shah                03-MAR-15 30-MAY-15
Santa Singh               03-JAN-15 30-MAY-15
Ankur Kahar               03-JUN-15 01-JAN-15
Jane Donald            08-JUN-15 01-JAN-15
There are 3 more records for Lidia Smith Ria

Comment: With that dataset it doesn't appear that there are any cases where the employee and manager have the same hire date - indicating that your query may be working perfectly by returning no matches

Comment: Among the results you posted, there are no records matching your condition on month, so "no data found" is exactly what I'm expecting. If even in the 3 not posted records there are no records that match the condition on month, "no data found" is the correct result, given that no record match your condition

Comment: There are 4 managers who have joined in the month of January and in emp5 table employee named Santa Singh has joined in January.So Why the query is not returning any tuple?Please explain.

Comment: If your join conditions are correct:  1): Santa Singh was hired in January    2) the manager of Santa Singh's department was hired in May   3) there are managers hired in January, but they are NOT the manager of Santa Singh's department, so they will not match.    If you need to match Santa Singh, for example, with every manager hired in the same month, even if he is the manager of a different department, your problem is NOT the date comparison, but the join conditions on the table `deparment`